# How to convert this MooTools code to jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have a certain problem when I try to Convert Mootools to Jquery.

```
var Site = new Class({
    Implements : Options,
    options : {
    },

    initialize : function(options) {
        // Set opzioni
        this.setOptions(options);
        var section = $$("body")[0].getProperty("class");
        // Chiama metodo
        if( typeof(this[section]) == "function" ) this[section]();
    },

    // Orerazioni di sezione
    home: function(){
      // Init scrollTo
      new SmoothScroll({ duration: 800, transition:Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut, offset:{"x":0, "y":-40} });
      // Definisce elementi draggabili
      $("handle").addEvent("click", function(e){ e.stop(); })
      new Drag.Move($('window'), {'handle':'handle'});

      $("logo").fade("hide");

      var ttop = $("simple-modal-title").getCoordinates().top + 100;
      window.addEvent("scroll", function(){
        if( window.getScroll().y >=  ttop ){
          if( !$("simple-modal-title").hasClass("fixed") ){ $("logo").fade("in"); }
          $("simple-modal-title").addClass("fixed")
        }else{
          if( $("simple-modal-title").hasClass("fixed") ){ $("logo").fade("out"); }
          $("simple-modal-title").removeClass("fixed");
        }
      }.bind(this));

      this.checkLogo();

      // Inizializza esempi
      this.initExamples();
    },

    checkLogo: function(){
      window.fireEvent("scroll")
    },

    // Smart Template
    templating: function(s,d){
        for (var p in d)
            s = s.replace(new RegExp('{'+p+'}','g'), d[p]);
        return s;
    }
});

window.addEvent("domready", function(){
   var site = new Site(); 
});
```

I don't really know if it is possible to convert successfully. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: ...MooTools *is* actually smaller than jQuery... 25kB vs. 31kB. Besides, for the things you do there, you'll probably need something like jQuery UI which is a lot bigger than MooTools More.

Comment: @Reanimation, look at his code above... does not appear that he'll need jQuery UI for any of that.  Looks very straightforward.

Comment: _"I have a certain problem"_ - what actually is the problem?

Comment: can you provide (jsfiddle) html code to show how it works please?

Comment: it will need some UI stuff. this is with `Drag.Move` and also a `SmoothScroll` class of some description. The code is not exemplary anyway.

Comment: @Sparky672, well, you're probably right, as I have no experience whatsoever with jQUI, but I guessed it'd be needed with things like dragging and smooth scrolling... pretty sure they aren't included in the main package :)

Comment: @Reanimation, I use third party or my own plugins for everything like that, and many times, you can figure it out without using a plugin.  I never found the need for jQuery UI.

Answer (score 4):

If I treat this as a question in the literal sense, the answer is:

1. Learn mootools.
2. Learn jQuery.
3. Write code to do it.
4. If you get problems, ask and get help -- by posting your newly written jquery code in conjunction with the old code.

As it stands, you are kind of asking for somebody to do it for you? this is not what StackOverflow is about, you should try a freelancer site for that.